# How to display probabilities instead of log-odds in stata

Tags: regression, probability, regression-coefficients, logit

I understand that logistic regression coefficients are to be interpreted as log-odds. i need coefficients to represent probabilities so i can say something like:

"the effect of [some dummy variable] increases/decreases the probability of my binary outcome equalling 1 by ....% ceterius paribus"

is there someway to get logistic regression results to be displayed in this way on stata? looking back at my undergraduate logit model notes coefficients are titled dy/dx and are bounded between -1 and +1.  is there some way to covert log-odds to probabilities? thanks :)

Comment: This question seems very similar to another question you asked earlier today. You're allowed to edit your question to more clearly explain you interest; in fact, it's encouraged that you continue to edit your question as much as is required to ask your question clearly, instead of posting new questions. Also, you're allowed to delete your own questions which do not have an answer with positive score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for (average) marginal effects, or in case of indicator (dummy) variables discrete differences. In Stata the command would be margins

Comment: Thank you Maarten. im fairly new to Stata. i tried (after running firthlogit regression) command   -margins, predict(pr) dydx(*)-   this did not work and returned error code r(198) as apparently option pr is not allowed.  this command has worked for me before when using the standard logit command. is this just a problem with firthlogit or am i doing something wrong?  if not, any potential workarounds?  thanks again!

Comment: my aim is to generate coefficients to estimate the linear relationship between covariates and pr(SALE), my binary dependent variable.